# How to install pyright on ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: node.js, npm, pyright

I want to install pyright on my ubuntu. To do this, I first installed npm (the most recent version):

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```

But when I install a pyright, I get these errors:

```
/home/user/.npm-global/bin/pyright-langserver -> /home/user/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/pyright/langserver.index.js
/home/user/.npm-global/bin/pyright -> /home/user/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/pyright/index.js
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for pyright@1.1.222: wanted: {"node":">=12.0.0"} (current: {"node":"10.19.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: pyright@1.1.222
```

Can you please tell me if this can be fixed somehow?

Comment: Read the error message, Update your node.js version to 12.0.0 or higher. https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#deb

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your NodeJS version is lower than the minimum required version (12.0.0). You need to upgrade NodeJS.

Clear the npm cache:
`npm cache clean -f`

Install Node’s version manager:

`npm install -g n`

Finally, install the latest stable version

`sudo n stable`

Comment: what is meant by "n"?

Comment: It's [Node.js version management](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n), as I said in the answer.